# Is it possible to undo an accidental click on “mark all as read “ at the top of notifications?

Tags: support, global-inbox, undo

I intended to tap on the first notification in the box, not the Mark all notifications as read button. What can I do to reverse this? I’m guessing nothing.

Comment: You can reverse it — by manually clicking each envelope to mark individual messages. In other words, no. I've lost a significant amount of marked messages by accidentally opening the inbox in places like chat that don't support the new inbox.

Comment: @Laurel true, better not click on the inbox on se.com as well, very big risk it will also reset the count, it has very old codebase patched to death. And needless to say, Area51.